# Use yearmonth column from groupby for creating timeseries R

Tags: r

`df` had columnns: `yearmonth`, `store`, `item`, `sales` .

`group1`: Aggregated df on keys store, item and year month and calculated total_sales for each store, item and yearmonth combination.

**Expected output:** Convert this groupby output to time series using group1 yearmonth without any NAN values in columns.

groupby top 3 rows: Name of groupby object: **group1**

```
[IN]group1
[out]
 store  item yearmonth total_sales
   <int> <int> <chr>           <int>
 1     1     1 2013-01           328
 2     1     1 2013-02           322
 3     1     1 2013-03           477  and so on

#Converting yearmonth to datetime before converting group1 to time series
group1$yearmonth = as.Date(as.yearmon(as.character(group1$yearmonth),"%Y-%m"), frac = 0)
```

Trying to convert groupby output to time series:

```
      > as.ts(group1)
Time Series:Start = 1 End = 30000 Frequency = 1 
      store item yearmonth total_sales
    1     1    1        NA         328
    2     1    1        NA         322
    3     1    1        NA         531 and so on...
```

How to use groupby yearmonth as key and create time series object without getting these NAN values?

Comment: First drop the column and then convert to time-series? `group1 <- group1[setdiff(names(group1), 'yearmonth')]`

Comment: yearmonth is the date column in the time series. If i delete that and how will I get time series

Comment: As far as I can see `yearmonth` is character column in your data. you are getting timeseries because you are using `start=2013, frequency=12` in `ts`. If you remove the column and run you still get same output.

Comment: You are right. edited this question. pls tell now. many year month combos are missing, so I want to use yearmonth combination of groupby for creating time series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can remove the `yearmonth` column and add it as index in an `xts` object.

```
ts_group <- xts::xts(group1[setdiff(names(group1), 'yearmonth')],
                as.Date(paste0(group1$yearmonth, "-01")))

#           store item total_sales
#2013-01-01     1    1         328
#2013-02-01     1    1         322
#2013-03-01     1    1         477
```

Or using the `zoo` library.

```
library(zoo)
ts_group <- zoo(group1[setdiff(names(group1), 'yearmonth')], 
                       as.yearmon(group1$yearmonth))
```

Comment: Both codes showing error.
1. `Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format` this is the error for the xts object.

 2. `some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique` this is the error for the second code
>

Comment: It means you have dates in `yearmonth` column in different format than you have shown. Can you check if data have some different format?

Comment: First error is removed. Date format used. Second error index entries in order.by not unique still exists. On doing `> anyDuplicated(group1$yearmonth)
[1] 61` 61 dupliacte entries I guess

Comment: you also need unique index values. One way is to remove duplicate values `group1 <- subset(group1, !duplicated(yearmonth))` and then run the above.